# React state change within event listener attached in a hook stops default behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling, dom-events

I have created a react hook that handles clicks outside a div. For this purpose I have attached a eventListener within the hook and i'm updating the state of a component in the event Listener callback. But this behavior stops the default behavior of elements within this div.

```
export function useClickOutside({
  ref,
  onClickOutside,
}: {
  ref: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>;
  onClickOutside: () => void;
}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleClickOutside(event: MouseEvent) {
      onClickOutside();
    }
    document.addEventListener("pointerdown", handleClickOutside);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("pointerdown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  });
}
```

The onClickOutside only does a state change:

```
onClickOutside = () => setIsMenuOpen(false)
```

If I dont invoke the onClickOutside() function call inside the handleClickOutside event handler, the normal behavior ( i am clicking on buttons within a navbar dropdown menu, that scrolls to the section (javascript smooth scrolling). But invoking the onClickOutside() only updates the state and the normal behavior of the button click is cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I figured it out that the reason for this behavior is due to the pointerdown eventListener. The pointerdown event captures all subsequent pointer events. Therefore, the element.releasePointerCapture needs to be called to release the pointer events according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/pointerdown_event).

I have figured out that replacing the pointerdown event with click event, solves my problem.

```
document.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);
```